# Rotating proxies don't get used in requests sent, but do rotate

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to change proxies after x amount of requests for checking username availability against an api. However, my function for changing proxies doesn't seem to change the proxies in the requests I'm sending. In the `proxy` function the proxies do change. Can anyone figure out why the proxies don't work in the requests sent?

(old) Code:

```
proxy = ''
proxyFile = open(f'external/proxies.txt', 'r')
proxyList = [line.split(',') for line in proxyFile.readlines()]
...
    def proxies(self):
        try: 
            if self.proxyCount > 0:
                self.proxyCount += 1
            proxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
            print('proxy in proxies function: ', proxy)
            return proxy
        except:
            pass

   def checkAccounts(self):
        while not self.usernames.empty():
            name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
            url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"
            try:         
                r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxy)
                print('proxy in check function: ', self.proxy)
                
                try:
                    if self.checkedCount % 100 == 0:
                        self.proxies()
                except:
                    pass

                ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"Gx | Checked: {self.checkedCount}, Available: {self.availableCount}, Errors: {self.errorCount}")
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                    if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:
                        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:          {name}")       
                    
                    else:  
                        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:      {name}")
                        self.availableCount += 1

                if r.status_code == 429:
                    self.errorCount += 1
                    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Error:          Rate limited")
                    self.proxies()
            
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Output:

```
[+] Taken:      name
proxy in proxies function:  ['222.74.202.234:80\n']
proxy in check function:
```

[Previous post about the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696593/changing-proxies-after-x-amount-of-requests)

---

Edit1:

```
    with open('external/proxies.txt', 'r') as f:
        proxyList = [line.strip() for line in f]
...

    def proxies(self):
        if self.proxyCount > 0:
            self.proxyCount += 1
        proxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
        print(proxy)
        return proxy
```

Output of Edit1:

```
85.214.65.246:80
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\OneDrive\Bureaublad\[+] Projects\Main\[+] Ubi checker\ubichecker.py", line 66, in checkAccounts
    r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 532, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 710, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the return value of your proxy changing function to `self.proxy`. Fixing that should make the proxy change

```
proxyList = [proxyIp.strip() for line in proxyFile.readlines() for proxyIp in line.split(',') if proxyIp]

def proxies(self):
    try: 
        if self.proxyCount > 0:
            self.proxyCount += 1
        proxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
        print('proxy in proxies function: ', proxy)
        return {
            'http': f'http://{proxy}',
            'https': f'http://{proxy}',
        }
    except:
        pass

def checkAccounts(self):
    # set the proxy initially, if not set already
    self.proxy = self.proxies()
    while not self.usernames.empty():
        name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
        url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"
        try:         
            r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxy)
            print('proxy in check function: ', self.proxy)
            
            try:
                if self.checkedCount % 100 == 0:
                    self.proxy = self.proxies()
            except:
                pass

            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"Gx | Checked: {self.checkedCount}, Available: {self.availableCount}, Errors: {self.errorCount}")
            if r.status_code == 200:
                self.checkedCount += 1
                if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:
                    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:          {name}")       
                
                else:  
                    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:      {name}")
                    self.availableCount += 1

            if r.status_code == 429:
                self.errorCount += 1
                print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Error:          Rate limited")
                self.proxy = self.proxies()
        
        except Exception:
            pass
```

EDIT: Seems your proxyList needs to be flattened first.

Comment: Thanks, but the `proxies` function completely pauses the program. Can you figure why? @abhijat

Comment: if I remove the `except: pass` I get this error:     settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  ```File "C:\Users\Gibbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 710, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: It looks like when you call `requests.get` the first time, the `proxies=` argument gets a list. And as per the `requests.get` code it expects a dict mapping protocols to proxies.  Looking at your proxyList it is a list of lists, so it needs to be flattened. Can you post the content of your proxy file from where you parse out proxy IPs?

Comment: output of your code: `proxy in proxies function:  ['36.91.45.10:51672\n']` so it do it as a list

Comment: I found a new way to get the proxies from the txt file, into a list, and then into a string. but it gives an error. (check the edit1 for info)

Comment: Yes you need to package the proxy into a dict as per requests API as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470245/1089912 - the latest edit packs the IP into a dict for http and https protoocols

Comment: But I don't want to disable them, so why does it give that error in the edit1 and what's the solution for it

Comment: The error is because you are passing a string to a function which expects a dict. You need to send a dict into `requests.get` as the proxies argument, which is what I edited my code to do.